# sqlalchemy InvalidRequestError

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, model, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using flask-sqlalchemy, this is not the first relations that i've built, but for some reason it gives me an error when i start flask:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'mapped class User->users'. Original exception was: 'Table' object has no attribute 'sender_id'
```

These are two models that i'm trying to connect via ForeignKeys:

User:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    about_me = db.Column(db.String(140))
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    #relations
    posts = db.relationship('Post', back_populates='author', lazy='dynamic')
    messages_sent = db.relationship('Message', foreign_keys='messages.sender_id',
                                    back_populates='author', lazy='dynamic')
    messages_received = db.relationship('Message', foreign_keys='messages.recipient_id',
                                        back_populates='recipient', lazy='dynamic')
    last_message_read_time = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    followed = db.relationship(
        'User', secondary=followers,
        primaryjoin=(followers.c.follower_id == id),
        secondaryjoin=(followers.c.followed_id == id),
        backref=db.backref('followers', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)
```

And Messsage:

```
class Message(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'messages'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sender_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    recipient_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    body = db.Column(db.String(140))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    #relations
    author = db.relationship('User', back_populates='messages_sent', lazy='dynamic')
    recipient = db.relationship('User', back_populates='messages_received', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Message {}>'.format(self.body)
```

I've checked the database itself and it certainly has sender_id in the correct table, tried to change "foreign_keys" parameter to directly name of model Message.sender... Tried to change parameters of lazy on those relations. It still gives me same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is subtle but `messages` in this case is a table so columns are referenced off of `c`, like `messages.c.sender_id`.  To use the column of the model class (the mapped class) you would do `Message.sender_id`.

So...

```py
messages_sent = db.relationship('Message', foreign_keys='messages.c.sender_id',
                                    back_populates='author', lazy='dynamic')

# OR
messages_sent = db.relationship('Message', foreign_keys='Message.sender_id',
                                    back_populates='author', lazy='dynamic')
```

There is some information here but it doesn't explain the table vs class situation: [handling-multiple-join-paths](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths) I think I would just use ORM style references until you are more comfortable and then you could use table references if needed.